# Ошибка установки pystemmer

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, pip, install

Вначале при установка была ошибка об отсутствии devtools c++. Установил их вместе со студией. теперь ошибка сложнее, не могу разобраться

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pystemmer
Collecting pystemmer
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/ee/19e0e4ec9398cc022617baa5f013fd415cce4887748245126aa6d4fac3c6/PyStemmer-1.3.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pystemmer
  Running setup.py install for pystemmer ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\73B5~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fevgw3de\\pystemmer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\73B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kn0wf886\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'Stemmer' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\runtime
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\libstemmer
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_danish.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_danish.obj
    stem_UTF_8_danish.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_dutch.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_dutch.obj
    stem_UTF_8_dutch.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_english.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_english.obj
    stem_UTF_8_english.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_finnish.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_finnish.obj
    stem_UTF_8_finnish.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_french.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_french.obj
    stem_UTF_8_french.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_german.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_german.obj
    stem_UTF_8_german.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_hungarian.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_hungarian.obj
    stem_UTF_8_hungarian.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_italian.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_italian.obj
    stem_UTF_8_italian.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_norwegian.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_norwegian.obj
    stem_UTF_8_norwegian.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_porter.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_porter.obj
    stem_UTF_8_porter.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_portuguese.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_portuguese.obj
    stem_UTF_8_portuguese.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_romanian.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_romanian.obj
    stem_UTF_8_romanian.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_russian.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_russian.obj
    stem_UTF_8_russian.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_spanish.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_spanish.obj
    stem_UTF_8_spanish.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_swedish.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_swedish.obj
    stem_UTF_8_swedish.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_turkish.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\src_c/stem_UTF_8_turkish.obj
    stem_UTF_8_turkish.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\runtime/api.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\runtime/api.obj
    api.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\runtime/utilities.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\runtime/utilities.obj
    utilities.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tclibstemmer_c\libstemmer/libstemmer_utf8.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libstemmer_c\libstemmer/libstemmer_utf8.obj
    libstemmer_utf8.c
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc -Ilibstemmer_c\include -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/Stemmer.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/Stemmer.obj
    Stemmer.c
    src/Stemmer.c(1754): warning C4244: дг­ЄжЁп: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ "Py_ssize_t" ў "int", ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
    src/Stemmer.c(1864): warning C4244: дг­ЄжЁп: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ "Py_ssize_t" ў "int", ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
    src/Stemmer.c(3222): error C2039: exc_type: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3223): error C2039: exc_value: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3224): error C2039: exc_traceback: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3225): error C2039: exc_type: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3226): error C2039: exc_value: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3227): error C2039: exc_traceback: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3250): error C2039: exc_type: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3251): error C2039: exc_value: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3252): error C2039: exc_traceback: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3264): error C2039: exc_type: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3265): error C2039: exc_value: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3266): error C2039: exc_traceback: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3267): error C2039: exc_type: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3268): error C2039: exc_value: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    src/Stemmer.c(3269): error C2039: exc_traceback: ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп з«Ґ­®¬ "_ts"
    c:\python37\include\pystate.h(212): note:  б¬. ®Ўкпў«Ґ­ЁҐ "_ts"
    error: command 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\73B5~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fevgw3de\\pystemmer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\73B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kn0wf886\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\73B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fevgw3de\pystemmer\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

1. Загрузите подходящий пакет whl для вашей версии Python;
2. Используйте pip для установки пакета, предполагая, что файл находится в папке загрузок: pip install C:\Users\Пользователь\Downloads\PyStemmer-1.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: Там вроде  Python :: 2.7 и максимально Python :: 3.3. У вас python37.